# Xticks different interval

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How do i set xticks to 'a different interval'

For instance:

```
plt.plot(1/(np.arange(0.1,3,0.1)))
```

returns:

[image]

If I would like the x axis to be on a scale from 0 to 3, how can i do that? I've tried

```
plt.xticks([0,1,2])
```

but that returns:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to learn about `plt.xlim` and adjacent functions. This causes the X axis to have limits (minimum, maximum) that *you* specify. Otherwise Matplotlib decides for you based on the values you try to plot.

```py
y = 1 / np.arange(0.1,3,0.1)
plt.plot(y)
plt.xlim(0, 3) # minimum 0, maximum 3
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 1]

Your plot uses only Y values, so the X values are automatically chosen to be 1, 2, 3, ... to pair up with each Y value you provide.

If you desire to determine the X too, you can do that:

```py
x = np.arange(0.1,3,0.1)
y = 1/x
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3]) # ticks at those positions, if you don't like the automatic ones
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.arange()` to get the desired range with a specific step:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = 1/(np.arange(0.1,3,0.1))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot(y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(y), 6), [str(round(i, 2)) for i in np.arange(0, 3, (3*6)/len(y))])
plt.show()
```

[image]
Also, you can see more examples of `xticks()` on the official matplotlib [documentation.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

Comment: I'm sorry but that gives the same out put as the second plot. I want it to span across the entire x axis

Comment: @dhj Ok, I will take a look at it

Comment: @dhj I have added an alternative with a list comprehension. I hope it's the desired output.